# Core Plot-Annotations when tapping a symbol

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm trying to show the value of a given point when the user taps on it, I've written the following based heavily on the Simple Scatter Plot example:

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"Plot: %@", plot);

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) plot.plotSpace; // Added in edit
    NSLog(@"xRange: %@", plotSpace.xRange); // Added in edit
    NSLog(@"yRange: %@", plotSpace.yRange); // Added in edit

    if ( _symbolTextAnnotation ) {
        [plot removeAnnotation:_symbolTextAnnotation]; // Changed in edit
        _symbolTextAnnotation = nil;
    }

    // Setup a style for the annotation
    CPTMutableTextStyle *hitAnnotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.color    = [CPTColor blackColor];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontSize = 16.0;
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";

    NSNumber *x = [self numberForPlot:plot field:CPTScatterPlotFieldX recordIndex:index];
    NSNumber *y = [self numberForPlot:plot field:CPTScatterPlotFieldY recordIndex:index];

    NSLog(@"x: %@, y: %@", x, y);

    // NSArray *anchorPoint = @[x, y];
    NSArray *anchorPoint = @[@32678400, @6720]; // Added in edit

    NSLog(@"Anchor Point: %@", anchorPoint);

    // Add annotation
    // First make a string for the y value
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    NSString *yString = [formatter stringFromNumber:y];

    NSLog(@"Y value: %@", yString);

    // Now add the annotation to the plot area
    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:yString style:hitAnnotationTextStyle];
    _symbolTextAnnotation              = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:plot.graph.defaultPlotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
    _symbolTextAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
    _symbolTextAnnotation.displacement = CGPointMake(0.0, 20.0);

    NSLog(@"Symbol Text Annotation: %@", _symbolTextAnnotation);

    [plot addAnnotation:_symbolTextAnnotation]; // Changed in edit
}
```

When you tap on a point the code runs and the following is written to the log:

```
2014-07-27 14:08:07.842 BodyTrack.It[301:26272] Plot: <<CPTScatterPlot: 0x1726f750> bounds: {{0, 0}, {750, 290}}>
2014-07-27 14:08:07.844 BodyTrack.It[301:26272] xRange: <<CPTPlotRange: 0x1726ef40> {425527680, 2678400}>
2014-07-27 14:08:07.844 BodyTrack.It[301:26272] yRange: <<CPTPlotRange: 0x1726efa0> {10780, 5720}>
2014-07-27 14:08:07.845 BodyTrack.It[301:26272] x: 427689780, y: 12000
2014-07-27 14:08:07.845 BodyTrack.It[301:26272] Anchor Point: (
    214102960,
    8000
)
2014-07-27 14:08:07.846 BodyTrack.It[301:26272] Y value: 12000
2014-07-27 14:08:07.849 BodyTrack.It[301:26272] Symbol Text Annotation: <<CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation: 0x1718f950> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x1718e9c0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {49, 23}}> "12000">}>
```

But the annotation doesn't appear. Any help hugely appreciated.

Comment: CPTScatterPlots have access to addAnnotation without going down the line like you're doing - [plot.graph.plotAreaFrame....].  Try adding the annotation with [plot addAnnotation:_symbolTextAnnotation].  I'm not really familiar with the annotations, but I think that should work...

Comment: Is the anchor point within the `xRange` and `yRange` of your plot space?

Comment: @weezma2004 thanks, I changed that and it still doesn't show

Comment: @EricSkroch Thanks, the anchor was outside the range, I'm not sure how that's possible given that I'm setting it to the point of the data? However, even if I hard code it it doesn't appear. I updated the sample code and log output

Comment: Your logged `anchorPoint` doesn't match either the logged `x` and `y` values or the hard-coded point in the edit. The `x` and `y` values are within the ranges, so if you use that point, it should show up.